# Reformatting Table of Contents to add indentation

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

For some odd reason my table of contents doesn't add indentation for each subsection.
Should I recreate it or can I reformat it? [image]

Note: there's a lot more content than just this, so it wouldn't be a two second recreate.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out one way,

[image]

Using the **Increase Indent** button

However there are two cases

- Case 1:  It works perfectly for the item
- Case 2: The item jumps all the way to the right side of the the Table of Contents, so you have to hit backspace at that line once, then add amount of spaces equivalent to an indent, or match it with the line above it.

Comment: This solution isn't very long lasting because as soon as you update the TOC the formatting will revert to how it was.

Comment: In Word 2017 the formatting change remains after updating the TOC.

Comment: @AndrewJens, did you right click toc, and say update all fields after?

Comment: @Iancovici, yes I chose the "Update entire table" option. All good.

Answer (score 0):

The ToC field can gather information from paragraphs of particular styles and TC fields. In the ToC, you can specify the level that you want each paragraph style to appear at. If you are using TC fields, OTTOMH you can specify the level in the field. When Word generates the ToC, it applies the paragraph style TOC1 to Level 1 items, TOC to to Level 2 items, and so on. So you probably either need to fix which paragraph styles (or TC entries) are associated with which level, or fix your TOCn style definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the TOC styles and fix the indentation. [This page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/word-help/format-a-table-of-contents-HA102322411.aspx) on the Office help site gives a good walkthrough on how to edit the TOC styles.

Comment: This link has since died.

Comment: Try using the Internet Archive to get a copy of the page and then update the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the tab setting in the TOC setup and *then* using the increase indent button (in TOC setup, not the Home tab):

1. Go to References tab >> Table of Contents >> Custom Table of Contents...>> Modify >> Select to Highlight **TOC2** (or the applicable level you need to fix) >> Modify >> Format >> Tabs...>> Clear ALL>> OK
2. Back on Modify screen for TOC2 (or applicable level you need to fix): Click the Increase Indent button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the right way to do it:

- Open the “text styles” dialog via the little arrow on the bottom-right of the styles panel or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
- Scroll to the "TOC 1" to "TOC 10" styles which correspond to the different TOC levels
- Edit the corresponding style

By doing it this way, the style is kept after refreshing the TOC (as long as it was built using an automatic style).